# Expecting value: line 8 column 1 (char 7)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a trouble when I'm trying to load a json from GitHub using python. My code give me this error **Expecting value: line 8 column 1 (char 7)**. But I don't know how to fix this.And I'm using python 3.6. Can anyone help me?

Here is the python code,

```
def check_for_update():
    try:
        print("Checking for updates")
        if check_connection(timeout=1):
            url = 'https://github.com/chenurawinrada/ZEGO-Bot/blob/main/metadata.json'
            rqt = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
            meta_sc = rqt.status_code
            if meta_sc == 200:
                metadata = rqt.text
                json_data = json.loads(metadata)
                gh_version = json_data['version']
                if version.parse(gh_version) > version.parse(VERSION):
                    print("Updates available!")
                    print("Go to https://github.com/chenurawinrada/ZEGO-Bot and update!")
                    talk("Updates available!")
                else:
                    os.system('cls')
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            pass
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit(0)
```

Here is my json,

```
{
    "name": "zego",
    "author": "maxmouse",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```

I tried using `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` but didn't work.

Comment: It's because https://github.com/chenurawinrada/ZEGO-Bot/blob/main/metadata.json is **not** a json file. You need to link to raw view.

Comment: Also you can just tell requests to return json `metadata = rqt.json()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the raw json file from github using the link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chenurawinrada/ZEGO-Bot/main/metadata.json instead of `https://github.com/chenurawinrada/ZEGO-Bot/blob/main/metadata.json` in your code.